# SSL Certificate Error

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, azure-devops, cicd

There is a web based application for the performance testing. Servers are physical servers.
Application works without proxy setting.
Script is Running successfully using JMeter in vm with the help of Host Entry Files.

After Integrating with Azure Pipeline getting as *Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message:url.com.

I have requested my hosting for DNS and got reply from them as done but still I can't able to login in local getting as connection failed[image].Asked the hosting team got replied as SSL certificate error.
[image]

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. DNS updates can take [up to 24 hours](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9622/10/dns-propagation-explained/) to propagate
2. If you need to add your custom hostname/IP mappings you can use [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) in JMeter
3. SSL error - you can ignore as it won't happen in JMeter, according to [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl)

   > **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.

With regards to the  `java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message:url.com.` - double check your hostname parameterization using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) as it seems that the placeholder is not substituted with the real value